# Apache Tapestry: Editable TreeGrid implementation

Tags: apache, tapestry, treegrid

I am (very) new to Tapestry. I've been trying to create an " Editable TreeGrid"; essentially a grid that gives me a functionality to collapse and expand rows based on a hierarchical structure. The edits to the data can be done on both aggregate and drill down levels. 
Going over: http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart7/ I have seen there is an editable grid,as well as a tree browsing structure, but don't really follow how to merge them into one structure. Is there something that's available out there in tapestry (or tapestry+jquery) world?

Example: Let's say I have an QA division in the company. It has 4 members. I have a column "Issues" stating issues detected. 
The tree grid should support display & modification of Issues column on both an aggregate level and at a drilled down employee level.

The structure I am looking for is similar to the one I found here:

http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=TreeGrid

(Look for "Editable TreeGrid" on the left hand side on the above URL)

I am looking for an approach/idea or some concrete implementation on how to get started with this? Perhaps all I need is a Tree view "that looks like a grid"? and don't really need to merge the grid and treeview functionalities together?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tapestry-resteasy](https://github.com/tynamo/tapestry-resteasy) library makes it simple to provide restful endpoints which communicate via JSON. I'd say that would be the simplest way to interact with this third party javascript library.

Tapestry also has built-in support for json via the [JSONObject](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/json/JSONObject.html). You can return JSON objects from event handlers and get the endpoint URL's via [ComponentResources.createEventLink](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ComponentResourcesCommon.html#createEventLink)